# How to get an integer value from string(may be url) in python

Tags: python, string, url

Suppose i had a url as below

```
url = 'https://www.advertise-example.com/ads/2022/presents'
```

Now i am trying to get the integer value `2022` out from the above url.we can use list slicing here, but the integer value can be increased, so i used regular expressions but couldn't get the exact result, can anyone tell me how to do this

Thanks in advance........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> url = 'https://www.advertise-example.com/ads/2022/presents'
>>> int(re.search(r'\d+', url).group())
2022
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from urlparse import urlsplit
import re

url = 'https://www.advertise-example.com/ads/2022/presents'
spliturl = urlsplit(url)
int(re.search(r'\d+', spliturl.path).group())
```

Possibly look at `re.findall` if you're expecting or want to handle more > 1 digit in the url...

Alternatively, not using re:

```
digits = [int(el) for el in spliturl.path.split('/') if el.isdigit()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using regex

```
>>> import itertools
>>> url = 'https://www.advertise-example.com/ads/2022/presents'
>>> int(next(''.join(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(url, str.isdigit) if k))
2022
```